# Evaluate $\int_1^\infty \frac{\cos x}{x}dx$.

Tags: definite-integrals, improper-integrals

I have a doubt, I know that this integral doesn't have an antiderivative but, is there a way to solve this:

> $$\int_1^\infty \frac{\cos x}{x}dx$$

Using Laplace transform or something similar?
I say Laplace because I know how to solve this by Laplace transform:
$$\int_1^\infty \frac{\sin x}{x}dx$$

Comment: What have you tried? Have you tried integration by parts? Show some of your work so other users can help appropriately.

Comment: It's the [cosine integral](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CosineIntegral.html).

Comment: see also here http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SineIntegral.html

Comment: Laplace transform is from 0.$\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin x}{x}dx$

Comment: What does it mean to *solve* an integral? $$ \int_{1}^{+\infty}\frac{\cos x}{x}\,dx = -\text{Ci}(1) = \int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{s\cos(1)-\sin(1)}{1+s^2}\,e^{-s}\,ds \approx -\frac{1}{3}.$$

Comment: @MyGlasses: that is not a big issue since $\int_{1}^{+\infty}\frac{\cos x}{x}\,dx = \int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\cos(x+1)}{x+1}\,dx.$

Comment: What can we do with denominator $x+1$ ? @JackD'Aurizio

Comment: @MyGlasses: the same we do for the sine integral. $$\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\sin x}{x}\,dx = \int_{0}^{+\infty}(\mathcal{L}\sin x)(s)(\mathcal{L}^{-1}\frac{1}{x})\,ds = \int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{ds}{s^2+1}$$ In such a case we may apply $\mathcal{L}$ to $\cos(x+1)$ and $\mathcal{L}^{-1}$ to $\frac{1}{x+1}$, leading to the identity in my previous comment.

Answer (score 1):

$$\int_1^\infty \frac{\cos x}{x}dx=\operatorname{Ci}(1)=-\gamma+\int_0^1\frac{1-\cos  t}{t}dt$$
and
‎\begin{eqnarray*}‎
‎{\cal L}\Big(\int_0^x\frac{1-\cos  t}{t}dt\Big) &=& \frac{{\cal 
L}\Big(\dfrac{1-\cos  t}{t}\Big)}{s}‎ \\‎
 ‎&=& \frac{\int_s^\infty\dfrac1s-\dfrac{s}{s^2+1} ds}{s}‎ ‎\\‎
 ‎&=& \frac1s\Big[\ln\frac{s}{\sqrt{s^2+1}}\Big|_s^\infty\Big] \\‎
 ‎&=& \frac{-1}{2s}\ln\frac{s^2}{s^2+1} \\‎
 ‎&=& \frac{1}{2s}\ln\Big(1+\frac{1}{s^2}\Big)‎ 
‎\end{eqnarray*}‎
so
‎\begin{eqnarray*}‎
\int_0^x\frac{1-\cos  t}{t}dt 
&=& {\cal L}^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{2s}\ln\Big(1+\frac{1}{s^2}\Big)‎ \right) \\
&=& {\cal L}^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{2s}\sum_{n=1}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n}\Big(\frac{1}{s^2}\Big)^n‎ \right) \\
&=& {\cal L}^{-1}\left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^{n+1}}{2n}\dfrac{1}{s^{2n+1}}‎ \right) \\
&=& \sum_{n=1}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^{n+1}}{2n}\dfrac{x^{2n}}{(2n)!}‎ 
‎\end{eqnarray*}‎
then
$$\int_1^\infty \frac{\cos x}{x}dx=\color{blue}{-\gamma+ \sum_{n=1}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^{n+1}}{2n(2n)!}}$$