# Is the integral $\frac{1 + \cos x}x$ convergent or divergent?

Tags: calculus, integration, convergence-divergence, improper-integrals, trigonometric-integrals

Does the following integral converge or diverge for $t\rightarrow \infty$?

$$\int_1^t \frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{1+\cos x}{x}dx $$

If anyone wants to know what I've tried so far, sorry, but I haven't looked at this sort of problem in years.  I'm pretty rusty.  The first term is obviously divergent.  I can tell that much.  I am wondering if the negative contributions from the $\cos x$ term are enough to prevent an overall divergence.

Comment: [It can be shown](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2472518) $\int_1^\infty\frac{\cos x}{x}\mathrm{d}x$ converges.

Comment: @J.G. since we’re only interested in convergence/divergence here, the exact value is irrelevant, so that link is unnecessarily complicated for our purposes here. A simple integration by parts proves convergence.

Comment: @peek-a-boo Good point. I just grabbed the first approach0 result, but since your answer is a more appropriate technique I've upvoted it.

Comment: The positive halfwaves give something minorized by the diverging harmonic series, and the negative halfwaves only make it worse due to the $+1$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It diverges to $\infty$. One of the things you should always try when dealing with oscillatory integrals is integration by parts. Let us ignore the factor of $\frac{1}{2}$. Here, we have
\begin{align}
\int_1^t\frac{1+\cos x}{x}\,dx&=\log t+\int_1^t\frac{\cos x}{x}\,dx\\
&=\log t+\left[\frac{\sin x}{x}\right]_1^t-\int_1^t\left(-\frac{1}{x^2}\right)\sin x\,dx\\
&=\log t+\left[\frac{\sin t}{t}-\sin (1)\right]+\int_1^t\frac{\sin x}{x^2}\,dx.
\end{align}
As $t\to\infty$, we have $\log t\to\infty$, and $\frac{\sin t}{t}\to 0$ and the last integral converges absolutely due to the $\frac{1}{x^2}$ decay. So, putting it all together, the LHS diverges to $\infty$.

So, the main culprit here is the $\frac{1}{x}$ term because that gives a $\log t$ divergence. The $\frac{\cos x}{x}$ term has sufficient oscillation (and an integration by parts reveals this) that its improper integral as $t\to\infty$ converges.

Answer (score 5):

DIVERGENT. HINT: For each $n \in \mathbb{N}$:

$$\int_{2\pi n}^{2\pi(n+1)} \frac{1+\cos x}{x} dx$$ $$\ge \ \frac{1}{2\pi(n+1)}\int_0^{2\pi} (\cos x+1)dx$$
$$\ge \ \frac{1}{2\pi (n+1)}×\frac{1}{4}.$$

[Indeed, $\cos x +1$ is nonnegative for all $x$ and so $\frac{1+\cos x}{dx}$ is lower-bounded by $\frac{1+\cos x}{2\pi(n+1)}$ for all $x\in [2\pi n, 2\pi(n+1)]$. Finally, use

$$\int_0^{2\pi} (1+\cos x)dx \ \ge \ \frac{1}{4}.]$$

Can you use this to conclude for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$ the inequality
$$\int_{2\pi}^{2\pi(n+1)} \frac{1+\cos x}{x}dx$$ $$\ge  \ \frac{1}{4}×\sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{1}{2\pi(n+1)}.$$

Comment: If the line between "hint" and "solution" is this fine, I have been skimping my students for years with the hints I've been providing.

Comment: @JakobStreipel I start out w a hint and then I keep writing and end up elaborating

Answer (score 2):

We have $${1+\cos x\over 2}=\cos^2(x/2)=\sin^2((x+\pi)/2)$$ Thus  for $t>1+\pi$ we get $$\int\limits_1^t{1+\cos x\over x}\,dx=\int\limits_1^t{\cos^2(x/2)\over x}dx+\int\limits_1^t{\sin^2((x+\pi)/2)\over x}dx\\ =\int\limits_1^t{\cos^2(x/2)\over x}dx+\int\limits_{1+\pi}^{t+\pi}{\sin^2(x/2)\over x}dx \ge \int\limits_{1+\pi}^t{dx\over x} $$
**Remark** The reasoning above can be used for proving that the integral $$\int\limits_1^\infty {a+\cos x\over x}\,dx$$ is divergent for $a\neq 0.$ Indeed for $a>0$ we have $$\int\limits_1^t{a+\cos x\over x}\,dx= (a-1)  \int\limits_1^t{dx\over x}+\int\limits_1^t{1+\cos x\over x}\,dx\\ \ge (a-1)  \int\limits_1^t{dx\over x}+ \int\limits_{1+\pi}^t{dx\over x} \\ = a  \int\limits_{1+\pi}^t{dx\over x} +(a-1)\int\limits_1^{1+\pi}{dx\over x}$$